# Maps mobile app for China with offline feature

Tags: china, maps, mobile-apps, gps-navigation

Is there a reliable mobile maps app for Android that works well in China and has an offline feature?

Baidu Maps appears to work well, but the interface is only in Chinese, so I am struggling with doing basic things like downloading maps for offline use or understanding why it is spamming me with multiple notifications every day.

Is there one with a translated interface?

Comment: *"why it is spamming me with multiple notifications every day."* Not sure about Android, but isn't it true that you allowed the notification? And isn't it true that you can disable it from the Settings app?

Comment: You've tried Google Maps, I suppose?  What was the problem with it?

Comment: @NateEldredge I am not in China at the moment, so I cannot try. This is one of the reasons why I am asking here.  However, Google Maps is known to be both blocked in China, and pretty unreliable there.

Comment: Related: [Downloadable maps of China](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/1006/32134) and [Is there a way to get offline maps of China for Windows devices as I have no iPhone or Android?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/82562/32134) or [Is there a usable online map site for China?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/21552/32134). None of them I would consider a duplicate, this is about an app that allows downloading maps for offline use, different from the related Qs. +1

Comment: @Szabolcs: If Google Maps allows map downloading on Android you won't have to worry about it being blocked since only internet access to Google domains is blocked. Both the app and the data would be on your phone. Of course they may be some bug or misfeature that causes it to not work properly without internet access but that seems unlikely if they specifically allow downloading maps, which means *means* offline is supported.

Comment: OK I checked and Google Maps does not have downloadable/offline maps for China. Apparently it's due to the licensing terms for the map data.

Comment: @hippietrail This was one of the first things I tried, but Google does not allow downloading maps for China (try it). There are also some reports online claiming that Google Maps is no longer accurate for China. Street layouts change amazingly fast there (I have seen this first hand) so I tend to believe this.  So far the two

Comment: @hippietrail I had my comment typed up, but went to check again just in case. I came back, pressed enter to post, and saw your second comment only after.  So far the only map I was able to find that is not Chinese-only and is reportedly reliable is Apple's maps (not available on Android).  OSM seems to have an offset issue.  It seems that the Chinese government requires using a coordinate system which is separate to the rest of the world, and this causes offset problems in some maps.

Comment: @hippietrail  But in the end it's not a big deal: if I was fine with no smartphone at all in the recent past, a Chinese-language-only map should definitely be sufficient.

Comment: All maps on laptops of China have the offset issue because China does something funky with GPS. However, some code was leaked that can fix this and I am guessing more and more map apps/sites have incorporated it. All the maps on my Android phone don't suffer from this and no Chinese made ones suffer from it. OSM may be offset in certain areas due to people trying to edit maps both with and without the GPS fix, as well as due to fast changing roads. I find Amap less annoying than Sugou for a China-only map.

Answer (score 7):

I had good experience in China with Maps.Me (no affiliation; that's the name of actual application on Google Play). It is free, open source, and it uses OSM maps. Works offline too.

In some remote places in China this app maps were a bit off the actual location - but so were Baidu maps/wechat locations.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that OpenStreetMap is reliable in China.  In which region/city did you try it?  Actually I did look at OSM but stopped reading at the point where [it was made clear that contributing to OSM is illegal there](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/WikiProject_China). But perhaps it is not enforced, so people can keep the maps up to date ...

Comment: Shanghai. The linked article says it is illegal to use GPS there in general :) but it is indeed not enforced.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's reliable. It has bugs and a lot of stuff missing. I've been using it for a month and a half. China develops very quickly and it's illegal for foreigners to engage in mapping activities in China so the maps necessarily lag behind. There have indeed been arrests but probably not for people adding POIs with their phones. In one village my hostel had at least three entries and one was several km off. A town in Sichuan was not on the map at all and in other remote places only the highway is shown with all other roads missing.

Answer (score 3):

Osmand is good for offline map. Especially, try a [modified version of Osmand](https://github.com/swkim01/osmand) that has OSM as well as chinese maps like baidu, autonavi, and even google map china with corrected position offsets. You can use them as offline if map tiles downloaded. But Cons is that the app version is out of date.

Answer (score 2):

While searching I came across OsmAnd maps. They offer offline maps and navigation, as well as a bunch of other features. OsmAnd served me well and I never had to look for a backup map.

If you speak a bit of Chinese, you can also take advantage of Baidu maps (iOS, Android). These offer a fantastic navigation interface in a form of AR. There are several other offline map apps that you can use as well. In case you use Chinese phones and don't have access to Playstore, you can use a third-party Android store like [this](https://apkpicker.com/category/maps-navigation) or Aptoide.